X-Cart encodes full colon to %3A in LINE App link which prevents LINE App to be activated, it needs the original :
I need to create a linkable image/text which activates the LINE App on a particular Account.
This is on an X-Cart Popup.
The program encodes the full colon : to %3A which then doesn't work to activate the LINE App.
Using any number of Script suggestions will make matters worse by inserting spaces etc within the scipt tags which renders ALL those links inoperable.
I need some script or html to prevent the full colon being encoded into %3A.
The program removes some scripts and html when saving!
♦ Original html:
<div class="class=">
        <a href="line://ti/p/~made-in-thai"></a>
        <a href="https://www.madeinthailand.co.th/images/content//made-in-thai_2.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>

♦ html after saving:
<div class="class=">
        <a href="line%3A//ti/p/~made-in-thai"></a>
        <a href="https://www.madeinthailand.co.th/images/content//made-in-thai_2.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>

